# How to get DHCPV6 server IP using C++ program. I tried using DHCPv6RequestParams but always gets error code 121

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

In Dhcpv6RequestParams i used it's first parameter as TRUE & FALSE. but I never get server response with it's IP address.

y code is as follows:

```
BOOL RetrieveDHCPInfo(LPWSTR pszAdapterName)
{
   DWORD dwError;

   int num = 0;
   CHAR TmpBufferV6[1000];
   DWORD initPtr = 0;

   Dhcpv6CApiInitialize(&initPtr);

   DHCPV6CAPI_PARAMS DhcpApiServerNameParamsV6 = {  0,
                                                    DHCPV6_OPTION_SERVERID,
                                                    FALSE,
                                                    NULL,
                                          0
                                          };



    DHCPV6CAPI_PARAMS paramArrayV6[1] = {
                                            DhcpApiServerNameParamsV6
                                        };
   DHCPV6CAPI_PARAMS_ARRAY DhcpV6ApiParamsArray = {
                                                    1,  // only one option to request
                                                    paramArrayV6

                                                  };



   DWORD size = sizeof(TmpBufferV6);

   dwError = Dhcpv6RequestParams(TRUE,
                        NULL,
                        pszAdapterName,
                        NULL,
                        DhcpV6ApiParamsArray,
                        (PBYTE)TmpBufferV6,
                        &size);




}
```

// I am receiving errcode as 121(Semaphore timed out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted microsoft regarding this. MSFT told that yet they have not provided any API which will return the DHCPv6 server address.

It is possible that in next releases they may give some API for the same.